# setState to window variable once on componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, components

I am trying to set my state to global variable within my `componentDidUpdate` function. However this is creating an infinite loop. I have prevented this using `previousProps` and checking against `this.props` for other situations but in this situation how would I only setState once based on my `window` variable?

```
componentDidUpdate(window.globalVar) {
    if (window.globalVar) {
        this.setState({
            lorem: window.globalVar
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving your code to the `componentDidMount`. It will be called only once when a component is mount. This is a good place to initialize your state.

Another good place is to use `constructor` of your class. But in constructor just assign `window.globalVar` to the state. Don't use `setState`

```
constructor () {
    this.state = { lorem: window.globalVar }
}
```

`componentDidUpdate` is called on every state update. To prevent infinite updates, you have to compare prev state with current state before `setState`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it within `componentDidMount` because it is `undefined` at that time. I want to continue checking `window.globalVar` until it is not undefined and then at that point setState once

Comment: Who is updating `window.globalVar`? Is it another React component?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(window.globalVar !== undefined){   // window.globalVar is not undefined
    if (prevState.lorem !== window.globalVar) { // prevState.lorem is not equal to window.globalVar
        this.setState({
            lorem: window.globalVar
        });
    }
   }
}
```